# JPA Criteria API: query property of subclass

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, polymorphism, criteria

I have a class structure like this:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Article {
   private String aBaseProperty;
}

@Entity
public class Book extends Article {
   private String title;
}

@Entity
public class CartItem {
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   public Article article;
}
```

I tried the following to receive all `CartItems` that have a reference to a `Book` with `title = 'Foo'`:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CartItem> query = builder.createQuery(CartItem.class);
Root<CartItem> root = query.from(CartItem.class);
builder.equal(root.get("article").get("title"), "Foo");
List<CartItem> result = em().createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

But unfortunately, this results in an error (makes sense to me, as `title` is in `Book`, not in `Article`...):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve attribute named title
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.SingularAttributePath.locateAttributeInternal(SingularAttributePath.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:189)
...
```

However, I was able to achieve what I want using the following HQL:

```sql
SELECT c, a FROM CartItem c INNER JOIN c.article a WHERE a.title = ?
```

So why does the latter work and can I achieve something similar using the Criteria API?

Comment: Aren't you missing `builder.select(root)`? Plus your criteria query does not correspond with the JPQL query.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Hmm, my `builder` (from `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar`) does not have a `select()` method. Yeah, they don't correspond because I am missing sth obviously ;-) Are you saying that I would have to add the JOIN to the `Article` on my own?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found a solution thanks to [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496099/chris) (see [JPA Criteria API where subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041735/jpa-criteria-api-where-subclass)).

For this you need JPA 2.1, and you make use of one of the [`CriteriaBuilder.treat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#treat(javax.persistence.criteria.Path,%20java.lang.Class)) methods. Just replace your `builder.equal...` line by:

```
builder.equal(builder.treat(root.get("article"), Book.class).get("title"), "Foo");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but from an OO point of view I would say that an Article does not have a property title and is therefore not found on the CarItem's property named article.

Maybe you should check if Article is of type Book.

I'm not sure how to do this using CriteriaBuilder

```
Criteria c=session.createCriteria(CarItem.class, "caritem");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("caritem.class", Book.class));
List<Article> list=c.list();
```