# Spring specifications - subclasses in joins

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, specifications

Let's say I have entities:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Person{
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private AddressEntity address;
}

@Entity 
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
public abstract class AddressEntity{
//some attributes
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "DETAILED")
public class DetailedAddressEntity extends AddressEntity {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STREET_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private StreetEntity street;
}

@Entity
public class StreetEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
}
```

I use Sprint Data JPA Specifications. I have a list of street's ids and I want to search for Persons that contain adressess with streets that ids are on that list.

Those are solutions that didn't work for me.

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<PersonEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    Join<PersonEntity, DetailedAddressEntity> join = root.join("address");
    Join<DetailedAddressEntity, StreetEntity> join1 = join.join("street");
    return join1.get(StreetEntity_.id).in(paramValue);
}
```

Causes: `Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [street] on this ManagedType [AddressEntity].`

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<PersonEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

    Path<Object> path = criteriaBuilder.treat(this.joinList(root, PersonEntity_.address, JoinType.LEFT), DetailedAddressEntity.class).join(DetailedAddressEntity_.street).get(StreetEntity_.id.getName());

    return path.in(paramValue);
}
```

Causes: `Invalid path: 'generatedAlias2.id' [select generatedAlias0 from PersonEntity as generatedAlias0 inner join generatedAlias0.address as generatedAlias1 where ( generatedAlias2.id in:param0 )`

When I move address from `DetailedAddressEntity` to `AddressEntity` all works fine.

Comment: Your `DetailedAddressEntity` does not extend `AddressEntity`.

Comment: You may try to navigate the other way around, like `select p from Street s join DetailedAddress da join Person p where s.id = ...`.

Comment: Now it extends. Sorry

Comment: I dont't think that the other way around would be possible to code in Spring Specifications, my root in this example is PersonEntity.

Comment: Of course, the root would need to be changed...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041735/jpa-criteria-api-where-subclass

Comment: As I said I tried: `Path<Object> path = criteriaBuilder.treat(root.join("address"), DetailedAddressEntity.class).join("street").get("id"); ` and `return path.in(paramValue);` as in link above but it didn't work.

Comment: Somehow it added in clause to sql but it didn't add StreetEntity to join: `select generatedAlias0 from PersonEntity as generatedAlias0 inner join generatedAlias0.address as generatedAlias1 where ( generatedAlias2.id in:param0 `