# Reference subclass properties in criteria API

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, criteria

I'm trying to build a query on a superclass, and optionally reference properties of a subclass (if the object is an instance of that subclass).

The EclipseLink wiki says I should use superClassRoot.as(Subclass.class).get("subclassField"), but it throws an exception: The attribute ... from the managed type ...[DatabaseTable(SUPER_CLASS)] is not present. The classes are mapped as @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED), so the subclasses have their own tables.

My expectation is that EL would create an outer-join to the child tables and optionally reference those joined columns.

Comment: Think that's same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903783/jpa-criteria-api-query-property-of-subclass (which is unfortunately without correct answer)

Comment: Why not just retrieve the root entity?  Instances of subclasses will be returned as well, and those instance will have the required properties.  ie "Select b from BaseEntity b where.." will return instances of BaseEntity and all its subclasses.  This is much simpler than "Select b.name, c.something, d.somethingElse from.." which will not work the way you might expect/want.  It is possible, but will involve extra seemingly unnecessary table joins because JPQL is designed around objects, not tables.

Comment: I'm selecting individual fields because I'm selecting across different entities, kind of like a flat-table mapped class hierarchy (and some joined classes as well).

Answer (score 0):

I would do that with two different queries, and then simply merging the results:

1. the first fetching instances of superclass (and not of subclasses)
2. the second fetching instances of subclass (with your additional condition).

If that is not a very important part of your application, this would work perfectl.